# Force lower case page number mark in citation

Tags: biblatex, capitalization

What's the best way to force `\pno` in a citation (`\textcite`, in this case) to lower case when it's upper-cased automatically?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}[force]{test.bib}
@book{Author2022,
author = {Some Author},
title = {An Interesting Book},
date = {2022},
edition = {1},
publisher = {P. Ublisher},
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{test.bib}
\begin{document}
See \textcite[appendix to ch.~V, \S~3, esp.~\pno~359]{Author2022} for more.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

produces:

[image]

I'd much rather have this say `See Author [1, appendix to ch. V, § 3, esp. p. 359] for more.` instead.

Comment: Why not simply use `\textcite[appendix to ch.~V, \S~3, esp.~ p.~359]{Author2022}` ?

Comment: That would certainly work here, but in general I prefer using commands like `\pno` that aren't language-specific but rather Do The Right Thing(tm).

Comment: But `\pno` is really only needed for edge cases: you are forcing BibLaTeX to recognize as page number, something that might not look like it (p. 27a, e.g.) It is not generally needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `\adddot`, then biblatex will not think that the period ends a sentence:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
See \textcite[appendix to ch.~V, \S~3, esp\adddot~\pno~359]{doody} for more.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect. Thanks!